# links show as unused imports

Tags: rust, rustdoc

Is there a way to include something into **documentation** scope without including it into the code scope?  My Rustdoc links to a Trait that's not in the code scope. If I add `use std::ops::Add` at the top, I get `unused import` warning from `cargo build`. If I don't add it, I get `unresolved link` warning from `cargo doc`.

In theory, `cargo build` should not warn me because rustdoc is in the same scope as the main code, but it does.

```rust
/// [Add]
pub fn foo() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fully qualify the link.

```
/// [Add](std::ops::Add)
```

Note that the syntax you've been using is shorthand for

```
/// [Add](Add)
```

and the thing in parentheses at the end can be *any* valid qualified name, including fully qualified ones starting at `std` or the name of some other crate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#[cfg(doc)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/advanced-features.html#cfgdoc-documenting-platform-specific-or-feature-specific-information):

```rust
#[cfg(doc)]
use std::ops::Add;

/// [Add]
pub fn foo() {}
```

Or just use the full name, as suggested by @SilvioMayolo.